# How to read a value from a response that comes as an array in Jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing

I have an api response coming as an array. `[{"data1":763,"data2":"jhgf"}]` How can i read a single value from this and assign it to a variable in jmeter. This value is required to pass on to the next request.

Answer (score 1):

Which exact value?

You can use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) for parsing the response and if you want `763` - use the following [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression:

```
$..data1
```

[image]

if you want `jhgf` - the relevant JsonPath expression will be correspondingly

```
$..data2
```

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)

Comment: Thanks. i did used json extractor but instead of using $..data1 like you said, i used $.data1.